# Internet Connection Change Job Service need to schedule everytime in activity?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, jobservice, android-connectivitymanager

I was reading [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring) for register a listner on network change for android pie and below versions.

I found out , for version above lolipop i can run a job service which monitor network changes.

So my question is 
 If it monitor network changes irrespective of the app is running or not. how do i take care this job service in my app activity life cycle.

curently what i have done is i am scheduling this job in onResume and stopping in OnDestroy in my activity. but i want it run on every network changes